# Mongoose opening too many Mongodb connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose/mongodb and would like some help on making database connections. I am observing that my express/next app is opening too many connections causing an alert on my Atlas hosted MongoDB.
I am making connections using mongoose(version 5.12.3) in a pretty standard way. Haven't defined any pool size (understand mongoose standard is 5) or timeout related issues. The connection is made twice - once for the application queries and second as a part of Mongo session store. I am just running 5 such node servers.
What I observed is - after reaching threshold, I killed each node server, one at a time. Still my atlas was showing some 23 connections. So I completely removed the network access to my node server and yet it took a while to come to zero. Then I started 2 of my node processes and I suddenly saw number of connections jumping to 60. As I do more and more activities on my node server, I just see this count ever increasing. And sometimes, without good reason, it shows a sudden dip. Also it's not that I have time consuming queries. Although I haven't measured time, generally the client side result is shown within a flash of a second. I am also not closing the connection on SIGTERM/SIGKILL.
I have following specific questions:

1. What are the recommended connection parameters for production usage?
2. Should I be closing connection on SIGTERM/SIGKILL?
3. What is the reason, for my 5 node processes, Atlas now shows about 70+ connections? The number varies with time - possibly correlated to user actions.
4. Is it that the number just kept on adding upon each bounce/restart of my node server and hence  one fine day it reached threshold?

Below is code I use:

1. To create mongoose connection for queries:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.INRMONGODB, 
    {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true}, 
    (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, "MONGODB CONNECTION ERROR");
        return false;
    }
    console.log("Mongoose Is Connected");
    }
);
```

2. As a part of sessionStore:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    rolling: false,
    name: process.env.COOKIENAME,
    cookie: sessionCookieOptions,
    store: new MongoStore({
        uri: process.env.INRMONGODB, ttl: 2000, autoRemove: 'interval', autoRemoveInterval: 20, // In minutes
        hash: {
            salt: process.env.SALTSECRET,
            algorithm: 'sha1'
        }
    })
}));
```

I also tried adding mongoose connection event handlers to see if anywhere any disconnection is happening - but that is not the case. Please guide.

Comment: Where are you creating your connection ? in server file ? would be great id you share complete code of connection file

Comment: connect-mongodb-session version 2.4.1 is used as MongoStore

Comment: Yes Rakesh. In server file. It's all part of my typical express server's app.js

Comment: MongoStore can use your existing connection. No need to pass new connection url.

Just store your previous connection in a variable and pass it to the mongoStore.

Comment: Ok. But will that solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use the existing connection for the MongoStore.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex:true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify : true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Database connected...');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Connection failed...')
});


// Session store
let mongoStore = new MongoDbStore({
                mongooseConnection: connection,
                collection: 'sessions'
            })
```

You might have look at my project where, I have used these things.

[Project source code](https://github.com/codersgyan/realtime-pizza-app-node-express-mongo)

Comment: Not helpful in my case